# Ansible Fact - Parsing Ansible Fact Variable to Dictionary

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-facts

I'm using Ansible
[os_project_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/os_project_facts_module.html) module to gather admin project id of OpenStack.
This is the ansible_fact log:

```
  ansible_facts:
    openstack_projects:
    - description: Bootstrap project for initializing the cloud.
      domain_id: default
      enabled: true
      id: <PROJECT_ID>
      is_domain: false
      is_enabled: true
      location:
        cloud: envvars
        project:
          domain_id: default
          domain_name: null
          id: default
          name: null
        region_name: null
        zone: null
      name: admin
      options: {}
      parent_id: default
      properties:
        options: {}
        tags: []
      tags: []
```

Apparently, this is not a dictionary, and I can't get openstack_projects.id since it is not a dictionary. How can I retrieve PROJECT_ID and use it in other tasks?

Comment: `openstack_projects` seems to be an array of dictionaries (indicated by `-`). Does it always have only 1 element?

Comment: Yes, I'm filtering projects by name, so it's always just one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `openstack_projects` facts contains single list element with a dictionary, we can use the array indexing method to get the `id`, i.e. `openstack_projects[0]['id']`.

You can use it directly, or use something like `set_fact`:

```yaml
- name: get the project id
  set_fact:
    project_id: "{{ openstack_projects[0]['id'] }}"
```